# firewall settings for VPN

Tags: firewalls, vpn

In my firewall settings there are options for "Allow VPN connections via PPTP" and "Allow VPN connections via L2tp-IPsec". All of my internet traffic goes through a VPN. Should I have these settings enabled or what do I need to find out to be able to tell?
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

- ask the person who set up the VPN what exactly it is (PPTP? L2TP? etc)
- use tcmdump (or wireshark on windows) to see what IP protocols and TCP/UDP ports are used to setup the VPN connection

or ... simply disable both, and see which one you need to enable to have the VPN go through.